# Meteors collection cursor forEach not working

Tags: javascript, meteor, foreach, collections

Why does the Meteor collection cursors foreach loop not work in the code below. If I wrap the loop inside a Template.messages.rendered or Deps.autorun function, it works. I dont understand why.

```
Messages = new Meteor.Collection("messages");

processed_data = [];

if(Meteor.isClient) {

    data = Messages.find({}, { sort: { time: 1 }});
    data.forEach(function(row) {
        console.log(row.name)
        processed_data.push(row.name);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Messages collection is not ready when your code is running.

Try something like this:

```
Messages = new Meteor.Collection("messages");

if(Meteor.isClient) {
    processed_data = []; 

    Deps.autorun(function (c) {
        console.log('run');
        var cursor = Messages.find({}, { sort: { time: 1 }});
        if (!cursor.count()) return;

        cursor.forEach(function (row) {
            console.log(row.name);
            processed_data.push(row.name);
        }); 

        c.stop();
    }); 
}
```

**Other Solution:**

Just play with subscriptions! You can pass a [onReady](http://docs.meteor.com/#meteor_subscribe) callback to a subscription
http://docs.meteor.com/#meteor_subscribe

Comment: So what this means is that when our browser loads the app, the collection is not ready. I dont understand what "ready" means.

Comment: The Collection is loading async. That means that it's kicking of the message-loading process and then proceeds with the code as usually. Then you are trying to access the collection with is not yet loaded in the async procedure. That means it's not ready.

Comment: in the code below, i tried the publish / subscribe technique. Works but the global processed array that i have, when i access it in the browser console, it is empty. if i console.log inside the subscribe callback, it is populated but not when i enter it in the console.

Comment: What is c.stop() ? Is it supposed to be cursor.stop() ?