# Fail to insert documents into a local collection

Tags: mongodb, meteor

This Meteor client code is supposed to insert all the documents from one collection into another, but `ToCollection.find({}).count()` returns `0`. Any idea how to fix this?

```js
//client/lib.js

toCollection = new Mongo.Collection('null');

Meteor.subscribe('fromCollection'); //<------FromCollection has many documents
FromCollection.find({}).forEach((doc) => {
  toCollection.insert(doc);         //<------but nothing was inserted
});
```

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16159533/meteors-collection-cursor-foreach-not-working

Comment: 1. Why are you providing the string `'null'`? Did you mean `null`? 2. You need to wait for the subscription to be ready before inserting the documents.

Comment: @MasterAM I don't know if null is needed. I read in the docs in order to make it local but I read on Discover Meteor that local means define in the local scope so I am confused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need properly created collections, something like

```
var toCollection = new Mongo.Collection('toCollection');
var fromCollection = new Mongo.Collection('fromCollection');
```

Notice

1. I've created both collections
2. The single parameter to `new Mongo.Collection` is the name of the collection, not a string with the value '`null`' in it.

Comment: If you want a local, in-memory collection, which does not sync to the server/database, you can supply `null` instead of the collection's name. Having a named collection that does not exist on the server will result in method errors as it will try to send the changes to the server.